# Not inserting into Database in CODEIGNITER Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, codeigniter

Not inserting..Any Suggestions??
DB Driver: mysqli
using Codeigniter.

**Controller**

```
function add_quote()
    {

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('invoice_no', $this->lang->line("invoice_no"));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', $this->lang->line("date"), 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer', $this->lang->line("customer"), 'required');
        if($this->input->post('customer') == 'new') {
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', $this->lang->line("state"));
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('gstin', $this->lang->line("gstin"));
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line("company")." ".$this->lang->line("name"), 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line("customer")." ".$this->lang->line("email_address"), 'required|valid_email|is_unique[customers.email]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line("phone"), 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[16]');
        }

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {

            print_r("helo World");
            exit;

            $form = $this->sales_model->process_form();
            $customer_data = $form['customer_data'];
            $products = $form['products'];
            $data = $form['data'];
            $dum = 'Q-'.$data['reference_no'];
            $data['reference_no'] = $dum;
            //unset($data['due_date'], $data['recurring']);

             //echo '<pre />'; var_dump($data); var_dump($products); die();
        }

        //$data1 = array('reference_no' => 1);
        //$this->db->insert('customers',$data1);
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == true && $this->sales_model->addQuote($data, $products, $customer_data)) {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', $this->lang->line("quote_added"));
            redirect("sales/quotes");

        } else {

            $this->data['error'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('error'));
            $this->data['inv'] = false;
            $this->data['q'] = true;
            $this->data['customers'] = $this->sales_model->getAllCustomers();
            $this->data['tax_rates'] = $this->sales_model->getAllTaxRates();
            $this->data['companies'] = $this->sales_model->getAllCompanies();
            $this->data['page_title'] = $this->lang->line("new_quote");
            $this->page_construct('sales/add_quote', $this->data);

        }
    }
```

**Model:**

```
public function addQuote($data = array(), $items = array(), $customer = array()) {

        if(!empty($customer)) {

            if($this->db->insert('customers', $customer)) {
                $customer_id = $this->db->insert_id();
            }
            $data['customer_id'] = $customer_id;
        }

        if($this->db->insert('quotes', $data)) { //Not inserted so Not enter into this loop

            $quote_id = $this->db->insert_id();

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $item['quote_id'] = $quote_id;
                $this->db->insert('quote_items', $item);
            }
            return true;
        }
        else{
            print_r("not inserted DATA");
            exit;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**Array Result:(Print_r($data))**

> Array ( [reference_no] => Q-SMGP/17-18/000003 [company_id] => 1
>   [company_name] => SMGP [vehicle_no] => dfg [date_time_supply] =>
>   2017-07-15 12:17 [place_supply] => sdafsd [consignee_name] => safsdaf
>   [consignee_address] => sdfsdaf [consignee_gstin] => 6556
>   [consignee_state] => sdfsa [consignee_state_code] => sdafaf [date] =>
>   2017-07-15 12:17 [due_date] => [expiry_date] => 2017-07-15 [user] => 1
>   [user_id] => 1 [customer_id] => 3 [customer_name] => Seed Arise
>   [total_tax] => 28.0000 [total] => 2100 [grand_total] => 2600.0000
>   [status] => ordered [shipping] => 500.00 [note] => )

Comment: check for your model validation. You might getting validation error there.

Comment: You're defining variables inside if statements, but are using them after, regardless if they are set or not. Then you're trying to insert the values without checking if they even exist. Check your error log.

Comment: Not exactly...Bcoz I tried Print_r inside the Form_validation()...and it perfectly works..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Error Log shows nothing bro

Comment: You should still redo your logic to handle different cases. Never assume that you're getting the correct data or that your method calls is successful. You should also dump the results as you go (in different places in your code) to see if it enters all the if's etc.

Comment: check if ```exit``` is the reason after ```print_r("helo World");```.

Comment: @kishor10d No bro...Its just for printing whether the condition is working or not...I just added it for testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution (28-02-2019):**

As per CI Docs ([Queries](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#handling-errors))

```
$this->db->insert('quotes');
print_r($this->db->error());
exit;
```

This will show if any error occurs else return an empty array.

> On my case it shows **invoice_no can't be null**

**Old:**

```
function add_quote()
    {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('invoice_no', $this->lang->line("invoice_no")); //This line is the Main problem...
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', $this->lang->line("date"), 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('customer', $this->lang->line("customer"), 'required');
    if($this->input->post('customer') == 'new') {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', $this->lang->line("state"));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gstin', $this->lang->line("gstin"));
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('company', $this->lang->line("company")." ".$this->lang->line("name"), 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', $this->lang->line("customer")." ".$this->lang->line("email_address"), 'required|valid_email|is_unique[customers.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('phone', $this->lang->line("phone"), 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[16]');
    }
```

> $this->form_validation->set_rules('invoice_no',
>   $this->lang->line("invoice_no"));

Mistakenly I just included this line...And I removed REQUIRED option...So it shows no error and do nothing..So when I removed this line, It perfectly working..anyway Thankyou all

Answer (score 2):

Check if table fields name. Beasuse of wrong field name insert may be not working.

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

Use this to find. It will give you the sql query of insert. Run it in phpmyadmin.

Comment: The array you given above in that [note]=> is empty that cause the error.

Comment: Its not a problem...I just included Form validation to an anonymous input field and I removed Required...So it could not submit the form and also it shows no Errors...
ERROR LINE:
`$this->form_validation->set_rules('invoice_no', $this->lang->line("invoice_no"));`
RESOLVED:
`$this->form_validation->set_rules('invoice_no', $this->lang->line("invoice_no"),'required');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

I have added two technique for `quotes` table insert query to check that data inserted or not.

```
public function addQuote($data, $items, $customer) {

    if(!empty($customer)) {

        if($this->db->insert('customers', $customer)) {
            $customer_id = $this->db->insert_id();
        }
        $data['customer_id'] = $customer_id;
    }


    if(!empty($data)){

        $this->db->insert('quotes', $data);
        $quote_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        // You can use one of this technique
        //one is the last inserted id
        // Second technique is described after this code

        if($quote_id > 0){

            foreach ($items as $single_item) {
                $single_item['quote_id'] = $quote_id;
                $this->db->insert('quote_items', $single_item);
            }
            return TRUE;

        } else {

            print_r("not inserted DATA");
            exit;

        }

    }       
    return FALSE;
}
```

This the second technique of `$this->db->affected_rows()` to check `quotes` tabke inserted a row or not.

```
// OR Second, You can use affected rows

if($this->db->affected_rows() == '1'){

    foreach ($items as $single_item) {
        $single_item['quote_id'] = $quote_id;
        $this->db->insert('quote_items', $single_item);
    }
    return TRUE;            
}
```

I am assuming that you have taken all column name correctly. 
Codeigniter has a log system to see what happing in the system you can use that here.

```
 log_message('error', 'Last query executed you can write here regarding log message: '. print_r($this->db->last_query(), TRUE));
```

In order for the log file to actually be written, the `logs/ directory` must be writable. In addition, you must set the “threshold” for logging in `application/config/config.php`. You might, for example, only want error messages to be logged, and not the other two types. If you set it to zero logging will be disabled.